# vue-text-transition not working in nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, transition

I am trying to use [vue-text-transition](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-text-transition) in `Nuxt.js`. But it stopped working when I tried to transition to `Nuxt`.

I think the main difference is that I am using `const showTitle = ref(false)` in Nuxt.js because I'm using composition api. Maybe something stopped being reactive?

Working demo (vue)
https://codesandbox.io/s/headless-voice-h18hg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Not working (nuxt)
https://codesandbox.io/s/vu-forked-0ddchs?file=/src/App.vue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution.

Just by adding `::v-deep` to each of the class ex:`::v-deep .v--vtt-test`, it started working.